# Jquery hover function show and hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Hover function that shows and hides my sub menus until a person hovers on them.

Problem is that when I try to move the mouse down to the menu that shows it disappears again.

Can anyone point out what im doing wrong here.?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-Link > a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('.menu').show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).next('.menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*background-color: #333333;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a.link {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li div.arrow-down {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li div.menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
nav ul li div.menu a {
  color: #333333;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
nav ul li a.link:hover {
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li a.link:hover div.arrow-down {
  border-top: 5px solid #808080;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
nav ul.right {
  float: right;
}
nav ul.right li:last-child {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
nav.color {
  background-color: #333333;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="left">
    <li class="menu-Link">
      <a href="" class="link">Home</a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">subcat.Title</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-Link">
      <a href="" class="link">Test</a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">subcat.Title</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a href="/">Basket</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you can try this https://jsfiddle.net/nnqyq3e5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the event is attached to the `a` element, therefore when the user tries to mouse over the menu which appears the `mouseout` part of hover is called on that `a` and the JS code tries to hide the menu again. To fix this, attach the `hover()` event to an element which holds both the `a` and the menu. In this case, the `.menu-link` element itself. You will also need to change `next()` to `find()` to cater for the change. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-Link').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.menu').show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*background-color: #333333;*/
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li a.link {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li div.arrow-down {
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li div.menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
nav ul li div.menu a {
  color: #333333;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
nav ul li a.link:hover {
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li a.link:hover div.arrow-down {
  border-top: 5px solid #808080;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
nav ul.right {
  float: right;
}
nav ul.right li:last-child {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
nav.color {
  background-color: #333333;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="left">
    <li class="menu-Link">
      <a href="" class="link">Home</a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">subcat.Title</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-Link">
      <a href="" class="link">Test</a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">subcat.Title</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
    <li><a href="/">Basket</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also note that you can achieve this in CSS alone without the need for any JS code, simply remove the `hover()` handler and add this line to your CSS:

```
nav ul li:hover div.menu {
  display: block;
}
```